# Connecting via FTP in vim does not ask for password

Tags: vim, ftp

I run this command from within vim:

```
:Nread ftp://myusername@passtomyhoster.com:21/html/
```

And vim prints out:

```
Name (passtomyhoster.com:mymacusername): Permission denied.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp: Login failed
```

So what's really strange is, that

- I'm not prompted for any password
- Somehow vim adds my mac username instead of the one I pointed out in the command
- the exact same line works on linux

Why's that?

Comment: What about `:Nread ftp://user:password@host:21/html/`?

Comment: Resolves into `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` ...

Comment: Also see `:help netrw-start`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a line like this to my .netrc file did the trick:

```
machine passtomyhoster.com
    login myusername
    password mypassword
```